# Largest possible value of a side

Tags: geometry, triangles

ABC is a triangle with side a, b,c with $a\geq b\geq c$ and

$sin^3A+sin^3 B+ sin^3 C=a^3+b^3 +c^3$

How do I find the largest possible value of a? I tried to use the law of sines ratio, but it didn't help.

Comment: Using sine rule, $8R^3=1\implies R=\frac12, a=2R\sin A\le 2R$. The equality occurs if $A=\frac\pi2$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Can you make it more clear? I did not get it/

Comment: @Sawarnik, Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines and $0<\sin A\le1$as $0<a<\pi$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The inequalities you gave I had understood, but I do not see how that gives answer to the question?

Comment: @Sawarnik, the max value of $a$ will be $2R$ when $A=\frac\pi2$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee And then? The original question?

Comment: @Sawarnik,focus on the basic ideas as you  should have been already done

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I do not see how that links to the relation $sin^3 A+sin^3 B+sin^3 C=a^3+b^3+c^3$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I just came across this, and this is so obvious :D I probably used to be more foolish then. Why don't you post it as an answer so its off the unanswered queue? :D